# Scala Compile Error Inserting into Postgres via Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, twitter, slick

UPDATE: The error regarding Projection vs ColumnBase has been resolved however I'm still running into issues the overloaded insert method.  The code has been updated to reflect this.

---

I'm trying to write my first moderately complicated Scala program.  I'd like it to read values from my Twitter timeline and write them into a postgres table.

I'm using twitter4j for the Twitter connection and Slick to write the data into postgres, however I'm getting two compile errors:

Error:

```
[error] /Users/trenthauck/Dropbox/Code/twitter-api/src/main/scala/org/trenthauck/TwitterApi.scala:45: overloaded method value insert with alternatives:
[error]   [TT](query: scala.slick.lifted.Query[TT,org.trenthauck.Timeline])(implicit session: scala.slick.session.Session)Int <and>
[error]   (value: org.trenthauck.Timeline)(implicit session: scala.slick.session.Session)Int
[error]  cannot be applied to (java.util.Date, Int, String)
[error]       Timeline.insert(date, id, text)
[error]                ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

My Slick Definition in file `DatabaseApi.scala`:

```
package org.trenthauck

import slick._
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
import Database.threadLocalSession

import java.sql.Date

case class Timeline (date: Date, id: Long, text: String)

object Timeline extends Table[Timeline]("timeline") {
  def date = column[Date]("date")
  def id = column[Long]("id")
  def text = column[String]("text")
  def * = date ~ id ~ text <> (Timeline.apply _, Timeline.unapply _)
}
```

My Twitter Definition in file `TwitterApi.scala`:

```
package org.trenthauck

import twitter4j._

import slick._
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
import Database.threadLocalSession

trait TwitterInstance {
  val consumerKey = ""
  val consumerSecret = ""
  val accessToken = ""
  val accessSecret = ""

  val cb = new conf.ConfigurationBuilder()

  cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
    .setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken)
    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessSecret)

  val twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance

}

class Twitter extends TwitterInstance {
  //get timeline
  def getUserTimeline() = twitter.getUserTimeline()

  //insert tweets
  def insertTweets() = {
    val tweets = this.getUserTimeline.iterator
    implicit val session = Database.forURL("jdbc:postgres//localhost/twitter",
                                            driver="org.postgresql.Driver",
                                            user="trenthauck")
    session withTransaction {

      Timeline.ddl.create

      while(tweets.hasNext) {
        var tweet = tweets.next
        Timeline.insert(tweet.getCreatedAt, tweet.getId, tweet.getText)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The connection to twitter seems to work just fine, it's inserting the data into the timeline table that's causing issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the mapping for `Timeline` class. Try this..

```
def * = date ~ id ~ text <> (Timeline.apply _, Timeline.unapply _)
```

Comment: thanks (+1), that resolved the issue concerning the projection vs column base however the overloading issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

What vidit posted means that you're mapping the default projection to the Timeline case class, so your insert should be using the case class instead of a raw tuple.

However, since your code sample defines the case class and the table to have the same name, it will probably still error out.  I recommend you at least rename your table, and then your insert would look something like `TimelineTable.insert(Timeline(tweet.getCreatedAt, tweet.getId, tweet.getText))`

Answer (score 0):

Change mapper object from: `object Timeline`

to: `object Timelines`

and then do `Timelines.insert(...)`

The built-in companion object of `case class Timeline` interferes with Slick functionality.

Look at all the [example code](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/lifted-embedding.html#mapped-tables) in Slick docs, the companion object is always pluralized, or removed entirely, using plain class/instantiation instead.